# Generating sequences of numbers and characters with bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have written a script that accept two files as input. I want to run all in parallel at the same time on different CPUs.

inputs:

```
x00.A   x00.B
x01.A   x01.B
...
x30.A   x30.B
```

instead of running 30 times:

```
./script x00.A x00.B
./script x01.A x01.B
...
./script x30.A x30.B
```

I wanted to use paste and seq to generate and send them to the script.

```
paste & seq | xargs -n1 -P 30 ./script
```

But I do not know how to combine letters and numbers using paste and seq commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure bash for generating the sequence:

```
printf "%s %s\n" x{00..30}.{A..B} | xargs -n1 -P 30 ./script
```

Happy holidays!

Comment: tnx @rottweilers_anonymous. how about three input. like ./script x00.A x00.B x00.C ! I tried a lot but I could not

Comment: @EpiMan `printf "%s %s %s\n" x{00..30}.{A..B}`

Answer (score 2):

```
for num in $(seq -f %02.f 0 30); do
    ./script x$num.A x$num.B &
done
wait
```

Although I personally prefer to not use GNU seq or BSD jot but (ksh/bash) builtins:

```
num=-1; while (( ++num <= 30 )); do
    ./script x$num.A x$num.B &
done
wait
```

The final `wait` is just needed to make sure they all finish, after having run spread across your available CPU cores in the background. So, if you need the *output* of `./script`, you *must* keep the `wait`.

Putting them into the background with `&` is the simplest way for parallelism. If you really want to exercise *any* sort of control over lots of backgrounded jobs like that, you *will* need some sort of framework like [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) instead.

Comment: tnx for your reply. I'v run the first one without wait, is it ok?

Comment: When I run it, I can not stop it anymore, is there anyway to have more control?